# My custom WebStorm Live Template isn't working

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I want to be able to type `todo` and then click tab and have it create the following `//TODO (My Name):` but when I created the live template with the abbreviation `todo` and I type `todo` in my JS file it doesn't do anything. `Cmd + J` does not show the todo template either.

Here is how I create it:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to indicate the position of the cursor after the template is expanded with $END$:

[image]

For more information:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/live-templates-2.html

When you are ready to use the template in your editor:

- just type: `todo`
- and then click <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Answer (score -2):

You should press Define on bottom and choose the particular context you want your template to work in.

You can see here that I have created a live template for console.log and I have chosen JS after pressing Define:

[image: Screenshot]